# Source location for a type definition from utop

Tags: ocaml, utop

In `utop`, can I get the source location for the definition of the type, say, `result` ?

```
utop # #show_type result;;
type nonrec ('a, 'b) result = ('a, 'b) result = Ok of 'a | Error of 'b
```

(defined in [pervasives](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html)

```
Result type
type ('a, 'b) result = 
|   Ok of 'a
|   Error of 'b
Since 4.03.0
```

but I am not sure how to get that info systematically)

Comment: The least you'd need for this to work is to compile OCaml with the `-g` (debug) flag. This will add source information in the compiled binaries. But even then, I'm not sure `utop` knows how to use such information.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but do you know you can get this information using merlin with emacs, Vi or VisualStudio ?

Comment: as well as other editors, see https://github.com/ocaml/merlin

Comment: May be that is the best answer. I tend to be fearful of too much editor integration out of experience of haskell tooling being brittle, but merlin seems really sturdy and emacs mode is a joy. Do you use utop from the editor integration mostly ?

Comment: c'est sympa de pouvoir pratiquer l'anglais entre nous :))

Comment: I had trouble integrating utop with tuareg mode, probably due to an emacs init files cluttered with legacy tuareg-mode tweaks, so I use the standard REPL.
But really, I use less and less the REPL as tuareg-mode+merlin gives me the type of everything, and tells me if it compiles or not, which is most of the time what I used the REPL for.